# How to convert String to int in Java while taking care underflow and overflow int?

Tags: java, string, int

I am converting String to int using following code:

```
int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");
```

How can I make sure int value does not overflow or underflow?

Comment: What do you mean by "best way to take care of overflow and underflow"? What results you are expecting?

Comment: The parameters of parseInt() must be a parseable integer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[As the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-), if the input string does not contain a parseable integer, a [`NumberFormatException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) will be thrown. That includes inputs that are integers but are outside of the range of an `int`.

The terms "underflow" and "overflow" aren't quite the terms you're looking for here: they refer to situations where you have a couple of integers in the valid range (say, 2 billion) and you add them together (or perform some arithmetic operation that achieves a similar effect) and get an integer outside of the valid range. This usually results in problems like wrapping into the negatives because of Two's Complement and such. Your question, on the other hand, is just a simple case of string-encoded integers lying outside of the valid range.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check:

```
long pre_foo = Long.parseLong("1234");
if (pre_foo < Integer.MIN_VALUE || pre_foo > Integer.MAX_VALUE){
    //Handle this situation, maybe keep it a long, 
    //or use modula to fit it in an integer format
}
else {
    int foo = (int) pre_foo;
}
```